# Running a loop while using telethon

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm making a telegram channel admin control script that needs checking channel in a loop. I also want some message handlers checking for messages. Here is a part of my code:

```
async def main():
    while True:
        .... (some code)
        log=await client.get_admin_log(await client.get_entity(chat),limit=1)
        .... (some code here)
@client.on(telethon.events.NewMessage)
async def message_handler(m):
    .... (handle messages)
client.start()
```

If i use client.loop.run_until_complete(main()), message handler won't work but main runs prefectly. and if I use client.run_until_disconnected() and run main in another loop using another thread, it stucks at get_admin_log. now what shall I do?
(I tried to run main in message handler when a specefic message arrives(I send it manually when I run it)
. it runned main but handled messages no more)

Comment: Try `client.loop.create_task(main())` followed by `client.run_until_disconnected()`. That should run both in the same event loop, which is what you want.

Comment: You should add an `await asyncio.sleep(10)` in your `main` to give chance for the other code to run. But do **not** use `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try async while, and if posible try to use another code(dont use while) beacase its endless.

Comment: `async while` is not valid Python syntax (at least not yet).